# Threads with lambda [&] leading to mystic results

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, lambda

I am currently developing a multi-threaded server (with c++14) and I am facing kind of a **strange problem**, let me explain:

So here I am just creating nb_threads threads with a lambda expression and putting them in a forward_list:

```
unsigned nb_threads = 4;
std::forward_list<std::thread> threads;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < nb_threads; ++i)
      threads.emplace_front(std::thread(
            [i, this]()
            {
              std::cout << "Thread " << i + 1 << " launched!" << std::endl;
            }));
```

This gives me this result on the stdout (which is **correct**):

```
Thread 2 launched!
Thread 3 launched!
Thread 4 launched!
Thread 1 launched!
```

Now let's **just change [i, this] by [&]** in the lambda expression:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < nb_threads; ++i)
      threads.emplace_front(std::thread(
            [&]()
            {
              std::cout << "Thread " << i + 1 << " launched!" << std::endl;
            }));
```

This now gives me this result on the stdout (which is really **mystic**!):

```
Thread 2 launched!
Thread 1 launched!
Thread 1 launched!
Thread 1 launched!
```

So my question is **What is happening ?** Why can't I change for **[&]** ?

Comment: `[&]` gets values by reference. Unless you specifically need that, use the first syntax you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Race Condition

What is happening here when capturing `i` by reference is a *data race*. When capturing by reference, each lambda will get a reference to the same memory location as the variable captured by reference.

Basically what is going on is that the main thread is writing to `i` while the spawned threads are trying to read from the same variable, without synchronization.

Performing reads and writes to the same memory location concurrently without synchronization will cause a data race and exhibit nondeterministic behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

As the value of `i` changes, the value of references to `i` changes with it. Since you have no synchronization, such changes are unpredictable. Here, you clearly want to capture `i` by value.

Answer (score 3):

This is no more "mystic" than the difference between

```
void thread_body (int i) {}
```

and

```
void thread_body (int &i) {}
```

In the first case the current value of the argument is passed to the thread and i won't change unless the function itself modifies it.

In the second you pass a reference to some external variable that is likely to change anytime, outside the function's control.

The only mystic thing here is the bloody awful C++ syntax, but since you're writing a multitasking C++14 server, you'll soon get used to it.